# Mongodb - how to group different fields inside a resulting embedded document

Tags: mongodb, group-by

I have a document that I want to group by some specific fields, and for the remaining fields that are not included in the groupby, I want to include them in an embedded array.

An example, let's say that I have the following data

```
[
{"owner": "A", "pet": "dog", "pet_name": "wouf"},
{"owner": "A", "pet": "cat", "pet_name": "miaou"},
{"owner": "B", "pet": "dog", "pet_name": "wouf_wouf"},
]
```

I want to group this data by the field `owner` and the remaining fields `pet` and `pet_name`, I want to group them in an array named `animals`.

Expected result:

```
[
{
    "owner": "A",
    "animals": [
        {"pet": "dog", "pet_name": "wouf"},
        {"pet": "cat", "pet_name": "miaou"},
    ],
},
{ 
    "owner": "B",
    "animals": [{"pet": "dog", "pet_name": "wouf_wouf"}]
},
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Query

- group by `$owner`, and `$push`
- we dont have an operator to remove a field from a document(remove the owner), so a literal document is used, to keep only the `pet/pet_name`
- finally rename `_id` to `owner` and remove the `_id`

[Playmongo](https://cmql.org/playmongo/?q=629cfde691b564fc1e7e9595)

```js
aggregate(
[{"$group": 
   {"_id": "$owner",
    "animals": {"$push": {"pet": "$pet", "pet_name": "$pet_name"}}}},
 {"$set": {"owner": "$_id", "_id": "$$REMOVE"}}])
```